# Connection reset by peer after several minutes in django celery

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, rabbitmq, celery

I have deployed a celery app for production but it disconnects from rabbitmq after 5 to 10 minutes after that no response is given from server
The error code is:

> [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

this is my celery.py file django project:

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from parrot_server import settings

BROKER_URL = 'amqp://parrot_user:Alireza@1234@localhost:5672/parrot'

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'parrot_server.settings')
app = Celery('parrot_server',
             broker=BROKER_URL,
             backend='rpc://')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request:{0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

It has 8 functions that 2 of them is called with `apply_async` function.
I look forward to your answer.
Thank you

Comment: Does it work at all during those 5-10 minutes? If not, it's probably not even connecting in the first place and that indicates a network issue (or bad URL as suggested below).

Answer (score 1):

Your broker_url looks wrong.  Here is the correct format:

```
amqp://username:password@host:port/vhost
```